# writing a mix of numeric arrays and text arrays to csv file in matlab

Tags: php, arrays, matlab, csv

```
file_name = 'Delta_SLAs.csv';
fileID = fopen(file_name, 'wt');

A = {'HRC-ID', '45700037'};
B = {'HRC-ID', '45700038'};
C = {'HRC-ID', '45700017'};
D = {'HRC-ID', '45700018'};

fprintf(fileID, '%s,', A{1,1:end});
fprintf(fileID, '\n%s,', txt{1,7}{14:end,1});
csvwrite(file_name, deltas_37, 1, 2); 

fclose(fileID)
```

*txt is the vertical text array
*deltas_37 is the numeric vertical array

writing in the string array works nicely but when I try to write the numeric array it writes over the previous data.

The task is to write the txt array and then write the numeric array in the column next to it to reference.

Same is to be done for next 3 sets of data which is meant to be written right below the previous data set

I feel like I am missing some little manipulation and it will all work. If anyone can guide to the right direction it would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: Would it be easier to create the array in matlab first how you want it, then csvwrite() it all at once, instead of using fprintf?

Answer (score 0):

[`csvwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) will always overwrite the file, but you can use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) instead:

```
dlmwrite(file_name, deltas_37, 'delimiter', ',', 'roffset', 1, 'coffset', 2, '-append');
```